# Motor driver only works on one side

Tags: motors

I have three motor drivers and all three other them only seem to only work on one of the two sides. I have used a voltmeter to check the voltages across the each of the two  sections on each motor driver. For all three of the motor drivers, two  of them had one side which had a voltage of 5 V (which should be 7.2 V as that's the power supply) and the other sides of the two motor drivers was 0 - 0.05 V (so effectively no voltage). The other motor driver had no voltage from either of the two sides. Are all three of the motor drivers faulty or have I broken them?

The schematic for the motor drivers was as follows:

[image]

(Apart from instead of a 12 V source a 7.2 V source is used but that's the voltage I need for the motors.)

Here's a link for the place where I ordered the motor drivers from [L298N Motor / Stepper Driver](https://thepihut.com/products/l298n-motor-stepper-driver)

[image: L298N]

Comment: You need to edit your question and add in the voltage measurements on the six lines between the microcontroller board and the motor controller.

Comment: electronics.stackexchange is the place for this.  EE site.  Obviously @Transistor operates fine in both environments

Comment: EE.SE would want a proper electrical schematic. This sort of diagram is referred to as a 'cartoon' over there! https://arduino.stackexchange.com might be better.

Comment: Can you share some details for the motor? Also Can you share some of your source code. These fairly simple to get it working.